# Yii - script file registers but never loads in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, yii

So I am able to load a boat load of other scripts outside of this particular widget that i'm working on in a yii project. and even in the widget i am able to get an external script to register and load. However when i attempt to register a script that is in my widget's assets folder it registers just fine (as seen in a `var_dump(Yii::app()->clientScript)` call) but it never loads in the browser. I have restarted my browser and that didn't help,  here is the output of `var_dump(Yii::app()->clientScript)`:

```
object(CClientScript)[10]
  public 'enableJavaScript' => boolean true
  public 'scriptMap' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'packages' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  public 'corePackages' => null
  public 'scripts' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'jwplayer-licence-key' => string 'jwplayer.key = "8xU8+r4etXrBAwrr4Rzyq8niCsNZYC01/6XuUw==";' (length=58)
          'jFileUploaderVars' => string 'var collegeId = 135717; var criteriaId = 0; var cameraMarkup = "<camera id="kdgtestcam" data-uuid="f89aee90-f319-0130-b0ac-12313940240c" data-videobitrate="131072" />";' (length=168)
  protected 'cssFiles' => 
    array (size=2)
      '/ednet/css/bootstrap.min.css' => string '' (length=0)
      '/ednet/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'scriptFiles' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          '/ednet/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js' => string '/ednet/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js' (length=29)
      '/ednet/js/jwplayer/jwplayer.js' => string '/ednet/js/jwplayer/jwplayer.js' (length=30)
          '/ednet/assets/6adc18e6/jfileuploader.js' => string '/ednet/assets/6adc18e6/jfileuploader.js' (length=39)
          '//cameratag.com/1.8/cameratag.js' => string '//cameratag.com/1.8/cameratag.js' (length=32)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          '/ednet/js/bootstrap.min.js' => string '/ednet/js/bootstrap.min.js' (length=26)
          '/ednet/js/profileDisplay.js' => string '/ednet/js/profileDisplay.js' (length=27)
  protected 'metaTags' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'linkTags' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'css' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'hasScripts' => boolean true
  protected 'coreScripts' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'coreScriptPosition' => int 0
  public 'defaultScriptFilePosition' => int 0
  public 'defaultScriptPosition' => int 4
  private '_baseUrl' => null
  public 'behaviors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_initialized' (CApplicationComponent) => boolean true
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

and here is my code:
`WIDGET:`

```
class JFileUploader extends CWidget {

    public $fileTypes;
    public $controller;
    public $model;
    public $criteria;

     public function run() {
       $this->registerClientScripts();
       echo $this->render('_jfileuploader', array('model' => $this->model, 'criteria' => $this->criteria, 'controller' => $this->controller, 'fileTypes' => $this->fileTypes), true);
     }

    public function registerClientScripts() {
      $assets = dirname(__FILE__) . '/assets';
      $baseUrl = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish($assets);
      $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
      $cs->registerScript('jFileUploaderVars', 'var collegeId = ' . $this->criteria['college_id'] . '; var criteriaId = ' . $this->criteria['criteria_id'] . '; var cameraMarkup = "' . CHtml::tag('camera', array('id' => Yii::app()->params['cameraTag-camera'], 'data-uuid' => Yii::app()->params['cameraTag-uuid'], 'data-videobitrate' => 131072)) . '";', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
      $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/jfileuploader.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
      $cs->registerScriptFile('//cameratag.com/1.8/cameratag.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
    }
  }
```

the widget displays just as it should the only thing that i can't get to work is the `jfileuploader.js` file and the `jFileUploaderVars` script to load in the browser. `Note:` the external script that will load is the last line in the `registerClientScripts()` method. the two above it will not. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the dynamic assets folder get created properly?  For example, does `/ednet/assets/6adc18e6/jfileuploader.js` exist?  If not, deleting the 6adc18e6 directory should force Yii to repopulate it . . .

Comment: Yes it is being created. I forgot to mention that I did delete everything in the assets folder so Yii would regenerate it all. But it didn't change anything. The folder was recreated and the js file was put in it but never loaded in the browser

Comment: What's the generated HTML show?  Is there an appropriate <script> tag being generated?

Comment: no there is no `<script>` tag being generated, alos as i mentioned before the view file renders perfectly, the script shows up in the clientScript variable, but never loads in the browser. using chrome, but it doesn't work in ff either

Comment: To clarify my first question, do the other script and scriptFiles generate in the rendered HTML?  Or are you not getting any <script> elements?  Looks like you should have 4 script files in the head and 2 at the end, as well as 2 inline scripts in the head?   And silly question, but is the above `clientScript` output generated in the view that you're having trouble with?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood, i AM getting `<script>` tags for all my scripts (ones outside and inside this widget) EXCEPT for the file `jfileuploader.js` and the inline script with the id of `jFileUploaderVars`,  and the `clientScript` var is being generated in the view, specifically being called in `registerClientScripts()` inside the widget, hope that clarifies and answers what you were asking

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but give a try to

```
Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.mywidget.assets'),...);
```

Comment: I'll give this a try in the morning